# Flow of piping to condense code when trying to expand a single property and format it

Tags: powershell

Here's what I have and what I'd like to do:

```
$SystemSize = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object Size -ExpandProperty Size
$SystemSize = "{0:N1}" -f ($beforeSystemSize / 1GB) + " GB"
```

This gives me the output I want in GB, formatted the way I want it. But how can I add the expression into the first line? I've tried to pipe it through a couple ways but I guess I just don't understand it. I don't want to put this into a table and spit it out, I need the data in the variable and most other code I've seen just spits this out in a big table. For example:

```
$SystemSize = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk |
              Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq "3" } |
              Select-Object SystemName, 
                  @{Name="Drive";Expression={($_.DeviceID)}},
                  @{Name="Size (GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f ($_.Size / 1gb)}},
                  @{Name="FreeSpace (GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f ($_.Freespace / 1gb)}},
                  @{Name="PercentFree";Expression={"{0:P1}" -f ($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size)}} |
              Format-Table -AutoSize |
              Out-String
```

As an addendum, I don't fully understand why the above works. Would love for an explanation. It makes a nice table but I'm lost on the `@{Name=...}` part of it all, is it doing a `Select` on the property using Key:Value?

Comment: For the last part, look at Calculated properties. That is what you are looking at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx  This basically allow you to do a select of each item but perform additional calculation before outputting the column, which you need to define a custom name and expression into a hashtable.

Comment: The term you're looking for is ["calculated property"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

Comment: Assuming $beforeSystemSize should also be the name of the first variable, then a subexpression would do the trick : $SystemSize = "{0:N1}" -f ($(Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Size) / 1GB) + " GB"

Comment: Thanks Sage and Ansgar. Looking into Calculated Properties, not sure why I didn't think of the sub-expression. I'll have to do some more homework, thanks again!